# In Zend Framework 2, how do you use a controller plugin outside the controller

Tags: zend-framework2

Specifically, I'm trying to use the FlashMessenger plugin form within my Module.php file.

Right now the method inside my `Application/Module.php` file looks like this:

```
public function checkAcl(MvcEvent $e) {
    // code to determine route and role ...

    if (!$e->getViewModel()->acl->isAllowed($userRole, $route)) {
        $flashMessenger = $e->getController()->plugin('flashMessenger');
        $flashMessenger->addMessage('You must be logged in');

        // code to redirect to login page ...
    }
}
```

But that is not working because $e->getController() is returning a string, not the controller object. Any help accessing either the controller or the plugin directly is appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the ControllerPluginManager to get an instance of the flashMessenger from any event handler in your Module.php like so:

```
public function myEventHandler(MvcEvent $e) {
    $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $flash = $sm->get('ControllerPluginManager')->get('flashMessenger');
    $flash->addErrorMessage('test');
    // ...
}
```

Obviously you can do this for any controller plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, thus Ezequiel solution works fine for me, you can use the following:

Make sure you use the class in Module.php

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\FlashMessenger;
```

And then:

```
$flash=new FlashMessenger();
$flash->addErrorMessage("hello");
```

I'm currently using Ezequiel's one.

Comment: Careful with this one - when you call hasMessages() or getMessages() the FlashMessenger will pull all messages from the session to the local FlashMessenger object (see the "getMessagesFromContainer" function in FlashMessenger.php).

If you instantiate a new FlashMessenger, and in the meantime something in your application has called hasMessages or getMessages on the instance in the Service Manager, your newly created instance will be empty.  If you happen to be first with the above code, any future instances will be empty instead (the first instance gets the messages).

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Mark T